# Form Authentication NO ASP.net Just C# & MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, login-page

How do i enable forms authentication for .net framework 4.0 just to look at MySQL Database for Username and Password and Access Level with out using asp.net 
Basically i want to have a database login IE USER***** Pass ***** port 3306 database accounts is login to database server then a secondary login that enables disables features depending on access Level set in database. I did it in 3.5 framework but i lost all of my code so i cant look back at it.

Comment: I figured this one out after conteplating a long time

Answer (score 0):

Just generated a table with account info in it yhen hard coded the permissions into program if uname access level is == 4 btn1.enabled = true btn2.enabled = true else{code here
} if uname access lvl is == 3 btn1.enabled = true btn2.enabled = false. So on so forth per access level permissions